# How to dismiss UIAlertController when tap outside the UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, uialertview, uialertcontroller

How to dismiss `UIAlertController` when tap outside the `UIAlertController`?

I can add a `UIAlertAction` of style `UIAlertActionStyleCancel` to dismiss the `UIAlertController`.

But I want to add the function that when user tap outside the `UIAlertController` the `UIAlertController` will dismiss. How to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Hi Leizh00701 check this out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466718/uialertcontroller-handle-dismiss-upon-click-outside-ipad

Comment: what the sender is :UIControl *aControl = (UIControl *) sender;

Comment: UIControl is the base class for control objects such as buttons and sliders that convey user intent to the application 
Please check this out 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add a separate cancel action with style `UIAlertActionStyleCancel`. So that when user taps outside, you would get the callback.

**Obj-c**

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"A Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
 // Called when user taps outside
}]];
```

**Swift 5.0**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message: "A Message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)             
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { 
    action in
         // Called when user taps outside
}))
```

Comment: This would not be standard behavior for Alert dialogs as they are designed to always be modal.

Comment: On iPhone UIAlertActionStyleCancel is shown (and tap doesn't work), and on iPad is hidden because it's replaced with a tap over view.

Comment: Your Swift 5.0 version simply adds a "Cancel" button that you can asign code to but tapping outside the alert doesn't trigger anything, you have to click on the button.

Comment: Same of me. The implementation above doesn't make the dialog dismiss on touch outside of it

Answer (score 56):

If you are targeting devices having iOS > 9.3 and using Swift and preferredStyle is **Alert** you can use snippet as below:

```
func showAlertBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "This is title", message: "This is message", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion:{
        alert.view.superview?.userInteractionEnabled = true
        alert.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertControllerBackgroundTapped)))
    })
}

func alertControllerBackgroundTapped()
{
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

With swift 3:

```
func showAlertBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "This is title", message: "This is message", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true) {
        alert.view.superview?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        alert.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertControllerBackgroundTapped)))
    }
}

func alertControllerBackgroundTapped()
{
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: As of iOS 9.3, you have to add the gesture recognizer to the second subview of the superview (`alert.view.superview.subviews[1]`) instead of the superview itself.
As stated in the documentation, the view hierarchy for UIAlertController is private so there is no guaranty it will not change in future iOS releases.

Comment: I have mixed your answers with sfongxing10000's, and I came up with adding the tap gesture to the `alert.view.superview` and all of its `subviews`. It's working for now, iOS 11.2!

Comment: Not sure if this is a change in Swift 5 but you have to add `@objc` to the `alertControllerBackgroundTapped` func, otherwise Xcode'll explain. Other than that the Swift 3 version also works with Swift 5, thanks.

Answer (score 42):

### Swift, Xcode 9

#### Dismiss AlertController with cancel button

provide action to your alertController where `UIAlertAction`'s style is `.cancel`

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
```

> Using this method alertController will be dismissed when user will tap to cancel action button as well as outside of the alertController.

if you don't want user to dismiss alertController after touch up outside of alertController, disable user interaction of first subviews of alertController in completion closure of present method.

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
     alertController.view.superview?.subviews[0].isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
```

#### Dismiss AlertController on touchup outside of Controller view

If you don't want cancel button in your controller view and want to dismiss controller when user touchup outside of controller view, do so

```
self.present(alertController, animated: true) {
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissAlertController))
        alertController.view.superview?.subviews[0].addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func dismissAlertController(){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: "Using this method alertController will be dismissed when user will tap to cancel action button as well as outside of the alertController." I don't believe this is true, when you tap outside alert controller alert, it does not resign the first responder. It only resigns the first responder when tapping outside of the alertController when using an action sheet.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using **Swift** :

Add an action with `addAction(_:)` and `style:UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel`.

The `handler will be called when ou tap on the button or outside the frame.

```
var alertVC = UIAlertController(...) // initialize your Alert View Controller

        alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: {
            (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) in
            alertVC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
```

**Objective-C** :

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:...];


[alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
   [alertVC dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}]];
```

Comment: Works nice, but is it possible not to show the "Close" button?

Comment: @bashan Yes, you must choose the correct `UIAlertActionStyle`. In this example I set the button to `Cancel` style. You can set it to `Default`.

Comment: Changing the button to Default will disable the functionallity of closing the menu when tapping outside of it.

Comment: Is there a way of pressing outside the menu to close it, but not having a "Cancel" button?

Comment: @bashan No, the iOS SDK does not offer that feature.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4:

Dismiss Action Sheet when User Taps outside Action Sheet created using UIAlertController

Code Snippet:

```
// Declare Action Sheet reference
var actionSheet: UIAlertController!

// Init and Show Action Sheet
func showActionSheetClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    // Init Action Sheet
    actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true) {
        // Enabling Interaction for Transperent Full Screen Overlay
        self.actionSheet.view.superview?.subviews.first?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        // Adding Tap Gesture to Overlay
        self.actionSheet.view.superview?.subviews.first?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.actionSheetBackgroundTapped)))
    }
}

// To dismiss Action Sheet on Tap
@objc func actionSheetBackgroundTapped() {
    self.actionSheet.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works when adding gesture recognizer in completion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in Obj-C:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle: ...
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{
                                       [alert.view.superview addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(alertControllerBackgroundTapped)]];
                                   }];
```

and then:

```
- (void)alertControllerBackgroundTapped
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES
                             completion: nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)addBackgroundDismissTapForAlert:(UIAlertController *)alert {
    if (!alert.view.superview) {
        return;
    }
    alert.view.superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [alert.view.superview addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(alertControllerBackgroundTapped)]];
    for (UIView *subV in alert.view.superview.subviews) {
        if (subV.width && subV.height) {
            subV.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [subV addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(alertControllerBackgroundTapped)]];
        }
    }
}
- (void)alertControllerBackgroundTapped {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES
                         completion: nil];
}
```

Comment: This actually works, as of iOS 11.2! I had to add the same tap gesture to all of the subviews too.

Answer (score 1):

```
    UIView *alertView = self.alertController.view;
UIView *superPuperView = self.alertController.view.superview;
CGPoint tapCoord = [tap locationInView:superPuperView];
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(alertView.frame, tapCoord)) {
    //dismiss alert view
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you view debug the superview of the alert, you see its not as simple as adding a tap gesture recognizer to the UITransitionView of the _UIAlertControllerView.You can do this instead

```
[presenter presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSArray <UIView *>* superviewSubviews = alertController.view.superview.subviews;
    for (UIView *subview in superviewSubviews) {
        if (CGRectEqualToRect(subview.bounds, weakSelf.view.bounds)) {
            [subview addSingleTapGestureWithTarget:weakSelf action:@selector(dismissModalTestViewController)];
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 15 it appears the view hierarchy for `UIAlertController` has changed yet again. It's presented as a new `UIWindow` that contains the controller itself. So in order to dismiss on tap outside:

```swift
present(alertController, animated: true) { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }

    let dismissGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.shouldDismiss))

    self.alertController.view.window?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.alertController.view.window?.addGestureRecognizer(dismissGesture)
}
```

and for `shouldDismiss` function:

```swift
@objc private func shouldDismiss() {
    alertController.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self button];

}

- (void) button {
    UIButton * AlertButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [AlertButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    AlertButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - 50 , (self.view.frame.size.height/2) - 25, 100, 50);
    [AlertButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Alert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:AlertButton];
}

- (void)Alert {
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert Title" message:@"Alert Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    [self presentViewController: alert animated: YES completion:^{ alert.view.superview.userInteractionEnabled = YES; [alert.view.superview addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(DismissAlertByTab)]]; }];
}

- (void)DismissAlertByTab
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
}
```