# Dismiss UIAlertViewController by tapping outside

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I want to dismiss my UIAlertViewController by tapping outside of the UIAlertViewController, on tapping on black screen space. I've tried this:

```
self.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true, completion:{
        alertViewController.view.superview?.userInteractionEnabled = true
        alertViewController.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertClose(_:))))
    })
```

but it just closes if I tapped on UIAlertViewController. But I want outside, where half-blacked screen tapped.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

```
@IBAction func shareButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let alertViewController = UIAlertController(title: "Share on social networks", message: "Where do you want to share?", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissAlertView:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    let facebookAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Facebook", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    }

    let twitterAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Twitter", style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Destructive) { (alert: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    }

    alertViewController.addAction(facebookAction)
    alertViewController.addAction(twitterAction)
    alertViewController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true, completion:{
        alertViewController.view.superview?.userInteractionEnabled = true
        alertViewController.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertClose(_:))))
    })
}
```

AlertClose function:

```
func alertClose(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Post your `alertClose` function.

Comment: I presume you mean UIAlertController? You may need to subclass UIAlertController, set the GestureRecognizer delegate to self, so you can then override shouldReceiveTouches:. This way you can return false when the touch is over the main window. This should give you the desired effect.

Comment: @Code done! I've added other parts of my code

Comment: Already ask question with answer [HERE.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075832/how-to-dismiss-uialertcontroller-when-tap-outside-the-uialertcontroller?rq=1)

Comment: @mitulmarsonia those answer did not help me =/

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ActionSheet style there is no need to do this. Because when you tap on half-blacked screen view controller automatically will be dismissed.

But if you want to use with Alert style do following (without: alertViewController.view.superview?.userInteractionEnabled = true) :

```
        self.presentViewController(alertViewController, animated: true, completion: {

            let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.alertClose(_:)))
            alertViewController?.view.superview?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)


        })
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UIWindow` class like
   `view.window.addGestureRecognizer()`
2. implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method `shouldReceiveTouch`
   and check your tapped view

Hope this help