# Using AlertRow with Eureka How to close Alert window when touching anywhere outside

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm using AlertRow in Eureka library.

Is it possiple to close Alert window when touching anywhere outside ?

[image: Eureka AlertRow]

```
<<< AlertRow<String>("categoryTag") {
    $0.title = "AlertRow"
    $0.optionTitle = "Pick a number"
    $0.options = ["One","Two","Three"]
    $0.value = "Two"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If you go deeper](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/blob/95b7cbcb3884e8fdc13910cbaf89cdaf049b5022/Source/Rows/AlertRow.swift#L34) you see that `AlertRow` is `UIAlertController` with `.alert` preferred style under the hood. There is no default implementation of closing alert by tapping outside the alertController, but you can subclass your own `XXXAlertRow` and implement this logic ([SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36568023/2463616)).