# In iOS, how do I close an Alert Controller by tapping INSIDE the Alert popup?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uialertcontroller, uicontrol

There are several posts regarding how to dismiss an Alert Controller popup window by tapping **OUTSIDE** the popup window. But I want to dismiss an Alert Controller popup window by tapping **INSIDE** the popup window.

I've seen a few "Toast" like solutions on GitHub, but I would like to do this with just native iOS code.

I've spelunked around SO and gotten the code to dismiss the alert after a few seconds (like Android Toast):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "SO Awesome!", preferredStyle: .alert)

    @IBOutlet var alertButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func displayAlert(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.perform(#selector(self.dismissAlert), with: self.alertController, afterDelay: 3)
        })
    }

    // dismiss (close) the alert popup
    @objc func dismissAlert(_ alert: UIAlertController) {
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

But what if I don't want to wait the 3 seconds for the popup alert to close?  I want to be able to tap on the popup alert to close it. (And also keep the timeout functionality)

I found bits and pieces of things that were close but not quite what I am asking for.  So ... after some work, I answered the question myself and have included a complete answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest trick I found on SO seemed to be to add a UIControl with an action target that dismisses the AlertController on any touch event.  But the UIControl requires a frame CGRect for it to function properly.

Here are the important points for the UIControl:

```
let dismissControl = UIControl()

// make the dismissControl execute dismissAlert for all touch events
dismissControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dismissAlert), for: .allTouchEvents)

// NOTE:  must use the bounds, not the frame for it to work
self.dismissControl.frame = self.alertController.view.bounds

// add the UIControl on top of the UIAlertControl view
self.alertController.view.addSubview(self.dismissControl)
```

I explored 4 different possibilities:

- **Timeout** - dismiss an Alert Window after a number of seconds (like   Android Toast)
- **Tap outside the Alert Window** (tap on Alert Window DOES NOT close it)
- **Tap anywhere on the screen to close it** (on Alert Window or outside of it)
- **Tap the Alert Window** (tap anywhere else DOES NOT close it)

And here is a complete ViewController **(Xcode 9.2, Swift 4)** that handles all 4 cases:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  AlertDemo - Display and dismiss UIAlertControllers with UIControl (no action buttons)
//              (similar to Toast on Android OS)
//
//      4 different ways to close a UIAlertController popup window:
//
//      1) Timeout - dismiss an Alert Window after a number of seconds (like Android Toast)
//      2) Tap outside the Alert Window (tap on Alert Window DOES NOT close it)
//      3) Tap the Alert Window (tap anywhere else DOES NOT close it)
//      4) Tap anywhere on the screen (on Alert Window or outside of it) to close it

//
//  Created by ByteSlinger on 2018-01-19.
//  Copyright © 2018 ByteSlinger. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "SO Awesome!", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let timeoutController = UIAlertController(title: "Timeout", message: "That Alert timed out!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let dismissControl = UIControl()

    @IBOutlet var alertButton1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var alertButton2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var alertButton3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var alertButton4: UIButton!

    // display a modal popup in the middle, wait for timeout to close
    @IBAction func displayAlert1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        alertController.message = "You must wait for this Alert to timeout"

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.perform(#selector(self.timeoutAlert), with: self.alertController, afterDelay: 3)
        })
    }

    // display a modal popup in the middle, tap outside popup to close
    @IBAction func displayAlert2(_ sender: UIButton) {
        alertController.message = "Tap outside this Alert to close"

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.dismissControl.frame = self.alertController.view.superview?.bounds ?? CGRect.zero

            self.alertController.view.superview?.insertSubview(self.dismissControl, belowSubview: self.alertController.view)

            self.perform(#selector(self.timeoutAlert), with: self.alertController, afterDelay: 3)
        })
    }

    // display a modal popup in the middle, tap on or outside popup to close
    @IBAction func displayAlert3(_ sender: UIButton) {
        alertController.message = "Tap anywhere to close"

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            self.dismissControl.frame = self.alertController.view.superview?.bounds ?? CGRect.zero

            self.alertController.view.superview?.addSubview(self.dismissControl)

            self.perform(#selector(self.timeoutAlert), with: self.alertController, afterDelay: 3)
        })
    }

    // display a modal popup in the middle, tap on popup to close
    @IBAction func displayAlert4(_ sender: UIButton) {
        alertController.message = "Tap on this Alert to close"

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: {
            // important - use bounds:  alertController.view.frame WILL NOT WORK
            self.dismissControl.frame = self.alertController.view.bounds

            self.alertController.view.addSubview(self.dismissControl)

            self.perform(#selector(self.timeoutAlert), with: self.alertController, afterDelay: 3)
        })
    }

    // close the current alert popup (middle) and display the timeout alert (bottom)
    @objc func timeoutAlert(_ alertController: UIAlertController) {
        if (alertController == UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController) {
            timeoutController.message = alertController.message!

            alertController.view.willRemoveSubview(self.dismissControl)

            alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.present(self.timeoutController,animated: true, completion: {
                    self.perform(#selector(self.dismissTimeout), with: self.timeoutController, afterDelay: 2)
                })
            })
        }
    }

    // dimiss (close) the alert popup
    @objc func dismissAlert() {
        // make sure there are no timeoutAlert calls waiting
        NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)

        alertController.view.willRemoveSubview(self.dismissControl)

        alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // dimiss (close) the timeout popup
    @objc func dismissTimeout(_ alert: UIAlertController) {
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make the dismissControl execute dismissAlert for all touch events
        dismissControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dismissAlert), for: .allTouchEvents)

        // make the buttons a little prettier
        alertButton1.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        alertButton2.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        alertButton3.layer.cornerRadius = 32
        alertButton4.layer.cornerRadius = 32
    }
}
```

To use this, just create 4 UIButtons in IB and connect them to the @IBOutlet vars and functions.

NOTE:  I had to cancel perform requests or sometimes the alerts would get cancelled by the previous timeout.  This line in `dismissAlert()` did the trick:

```
NSObject.cancelPreviousPerformRequests(withTarget: self)
```

Here is the full Xcode project on GitHub:  [AlertDemo](https://github.com/ByteSlinger/AlertDemo)

Thanks to **@Apoc** and his inspiration with `UIControl` in this post:  [UIAlertController handle dismiss upon click outside (IPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466718/uialertcontroller-handle-dismiss-upon-click-outside-ipad).  Setting the UIControl frame from the UIAlertController bounds was what finally got it to work.