# How to hide a Alert or dissmiss Alert when click on view

Tags: ios, swift

I want to  hide my alert when any one click on view. [Logout alert should be hide when click on black shadow area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ2Yw.png)

please anyone help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dismiss UIAlertController when tap outside the UIAlertController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075832/how-to-dismiss-uialertcontroller-when-tap-outside-the-uialertcontroller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIAlertController handle dismiss upon click outside (IPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466718/uialertcontroller-handle-dismiss-upon-click-outside-ipad)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to enable the interaction for the superview of the alert.

```
myAlert.view.superview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

then you have to add a click gesture to superview which inturn will dismiss your view.

```
myAlert.view.superview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.removeAlert)))
```